# Краш приложения при выполнении действия на фрагменте

Tags: java, android

Программа для решения квадратных, биквадратных уравнений. Есть одна активность и 4 фрагмента. При запуске программы, главная активность загружает первый фрагмент. На первом фрагменте все решается отлично. При переходе на 2 фрагмент (биквадратные уравнения) и нажатия на кнопку "решить" приложение вылетает с такой ошибкой:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at helmus.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:115),
```

где 115 строка это:

```
xa.setText("Корней нет");
```

+Ко всему прочему, если при запуске нажать на кнопку "очистить" (стирает все введенные и установленные данные с полей для ввода текста) программа вылетает.
Перед

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
```

идет

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

активити

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            b1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            c1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            d1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
            xa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
            xb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
            xa1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
            xa2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
            xa3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
            xa4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
            double x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x11 = 0, x22 = 0, x33 = 0, x44 = 0;
            if ((a1.getText().toString().equals("")) & (b1.getText().toString().equals("")) & (c1.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Введи хотя бы 1 коэффициент :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } else {
                if (a1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    a = 1;
                    a1.setText("1");
                } else {
                    a = Double.parseDouble(a1.getText().toString());
                }
                if (b1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    b = 1;
                    b1.setText("1");
                } else {
                    b = Double.parseDouble(b1.getText().toString());
                }
                if (c1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    c = 0;
                    c1.setText("0");
                } else {
                    c = Double.parseDouble(c1.getText().toString());
                }
                double d = (b * b - 4 * a * c);
                String discr = String.valueOf(d);
                d1.setText(discr);
                if (d < 0) {
                    xa.setText("Корней нет");
                    xb.setText("Корней нет");
                    xa1.setText("Корней нет");
                    xa2.setText("Корней нет");
                    xa3.setText("Корней нет");
                    xa4.setText("Корней нет");
                }
                else {
                    x1 = ((-1) * b + Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
                    x2 = ((-1) * b - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
                    x11 = (Math.sqrt(((-1) * b - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)));
                    x22 = (-1) * (Math.sqrt(((-1) * b - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)));
                    x33 = (Math.sqrt(((-1) * b + Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)));
                    x44 = ((-1) * (Math.sqrt(((-1) * b + Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a))));

                    String coren1 = String.valueOf(x1);
                    String coren2 = String.valueOf(x2);
                    String coren11 = String.valueOf(x11);
                    String coren22 = String.valueOf(x22);
                    String coren33 = String.valueOf(x33);
                    String coren44 = String.valueOf(x44);

                    xa.setText(coren1);
                    xb.setText(coren2);
                    xa1.setText(coren11);
                    xa2.setText(coren22);
                    xa3.setText(coren33);
                    xa4.setText(coren44);
                }
                Snackbar.make(view, "Уравнение решено :)", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();}
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
    fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            d1.setText(null);
            xa.setText(null);
            xb.setText(null);
            a1.setText(null);
            b1.setText(null);
            c1.setText(null);
            xa1.setText(null);
            xa2.setText(null);
            xa3.setText(null);
            xa4.setText(null);
        }
    });

    f_quad = new BlankFragment();
    f_biquad = new BlankFragment_1();
    f_triquad = new BlankFragment_2();
    f_teor = new BlankFragment_3();
    f_trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    f_trans.add(R.id.cont, f_quad).commit();
```

Comment: В данный момент ничего не понятно, акромя того, что `xa` у вас `null`. Уж не во фрагменте ли он? Если да, то обращаться к разметке фрагмента из активити не надо.

Comment: такой код не скомпилируется. Вы что-то потеряли между вашим `IDE` и `RU.SO`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, xa, xb, xa1 ... xa4, находятся во фрагментах. Если к ним из активити обращаться нельзя, то что делать в этом случае? Работать параметрами Visibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог перенос всех вычислений в `Java` классы всех фрагментов и обращение к разметке фрагмента уже оттуда. Простите глупость новичка и спасибо, @ЮрийСПб )

Answer (score 1):

Как вы можете на `fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`обращаться к вашим EditText если они у вас инициализируются в  `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`, когда вы нажимаете на fab2 у вас скорее всего EditText еще не инициализированы.

Comment: спасибо, исправил банальным копированием инициализации EditText-ов в onClick второго fab-а. Правда это ответ ко второй проблеме, решив которую, я столкнулся с первой: при нажатии теперь уже на fab2 программа крашится с указанием на xa.settext(null);

Comment: setText(null) замените на setText("")

Comment: Объвите EditText глобально в Activity и инициализируйте их в теле метода onCreate.